# Possible To Get Around Converting To Decimal for Django DB Saves?

Tags: mysql, django, decimal

While testing out some of our save task performances on Django (bulk_create),

I noticed in a cProfile test that prior to saving, django runs a get_db_prep_save, which calls a value_to_db_decimal. However, because we have so many rows (dealing with financial data) we are updating at a time, the cumulative time is over 20 seconds for this process. You can see the amount of calls made in the ncalls.

cProfile

```
ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
328166    0.344    0.000   21.733    0.000 __init__.py:891(get_db_prep_save)
328166    0.334    0.000   20.521    0.000 __init__.py:860(value_to_db_decimal)
309035    1.253    0.000   20.288    0.000 util.py:142(format_number)
```

I've attempted creating Django objects with DecimalFields set up exactly to our Django models.py (4 Decimal places) using Decimal(x).quantize(.0004), but no matter what I do, this specific function ends up taking 20+ seconds. (I was secretly hoping by passing Decimal types, it wouldn't need to be reformatted by Django.) Is there a way I can get around this when I create the Django object to be saved into MySQL?

One option seems to be override get_db_prep_save, but I'm just wondering if there's something simpler I'm missing. Thanks!

Comment: Have you examined the source of `DecimalField` yet?

Comment: Yep! DecimalField in the documentation refers to using decimal in python, which is what we're using when creating the Django object. What surprises me is still why it attempts to convert a Decimal to Decimal (and as a result takes such a long time).